Kamal Error docker stderr: Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Trying to set up a Rails deploy with Kamal using Docker Hub. I am using a token which seemingly works with:
$ docker login -u username -p api-key
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded

Here is the deploy.yml
service: app-name

image: mterenzio/app-name

servers:
  web:
    - 192.168.0.1

proxy: 
  ssl: true
  host: example.com

registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  username:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME

  # Always use an access token rather than real password (pulled from .kamal/secrets).
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Configure builder setup.
builder:
  arch: amd64

env:
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY

.env has the values set with my values replaced here:
KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME = "username"
KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD = "api-key"
RAILS_MASTER_KEY = "rails-master-key"

.kamal secrets file has:
KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME=$KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME
KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$RAILS_MASTER_KEY

Is there some docker or kamal config I'm missing to avoid the interactive prompt?
I tried kamal setup
Was expecting it to create the docker image on the registry

Apparent issue with reading .env file or the .secrets file because putting the username and password inline successfully ran the setup
